# Can authorize method in Request class return customized message for HandlesAuthorization trait?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-authorization, laravel-request

I have the following code in Request class to check if the user is authorized to perform update.

`HandlesAuthorization trait`, by default gives default message. Is there any way to return customized message? I saw the authorize method in `Request class` can `return boolean` value only.

```
class UpdateRoleRequest extends Request
{
    private $UserPermissionsSession;

    public function __construct(IRole $Role) {
        $this->UserPermissionsSession = new UserPermissionsSession();
    }

    public function authorize() {
        $UserID = \Auth::user()->UserID;
        return $this->UserPermissionsSession->CheckPermissionExists($UserID);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can implement failedAuthorization method on request

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you shouldn't look at `HandlesAuthorization` trait. All you need to do is implementing `failedAuthorization` method in your request class.

In `FormRequest` class it's defined like this:

```
/**
 * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
 */
protected function failedAuthorization()
{
    throw new AuthorizationException('This action is unauthorized.');
}
```

so all you need is to override this method in your `UpdateRoleRequest` class for example like this:

```
protected function failedAuthorization()
{
    throw new \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException('User has to be an admin.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but what if i want to have this custom message only in one condition? I want to send that custom message only if a condition is true, otherwise i want another check that has nothing to do with user being admin, and i want default message in that case.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately some one deleted your answer and took the chance to make this page better....

Answer (score 1):

To provide a solution answering @Pooria Honarmand's question for anyone else wondering the same;
If you have more specific messages for different conditions that you already checked in the `authorize` method and you don't want to repeat those checks here, just introduce one or more class-based variables.

Here is one example having only one condition which does result in a non-standard message:
private bool $hasMissingClientId = false;

```
public function authorize(): bool
{
    // several other checks

    if (empty($user->client_id)) {
        $this->hasMissingClientId = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

protected function failedAuthorization()
{
    if ($this->hasMissingClientId) {
        throw new AuthorizationException('User has to be assigned to specific client.');
    }
    parent::failedAuthorization();
}
```